# Prevent a formatted phone number from having 10 repeated numbers RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a phone number regex, which must be in format nnn-nnn-nnnn or n-nnn-nnn-nnnn (n for number).

the regex for this is

```
^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

I need to prevent phone numbers with all 1s, all 2s, all 3s, ect.

I have a pattern that will pass if there is 10 of same character, but I want the reverse of this, there cannot be 10 of the same character, and I need to stick that into a negative lookahead so I can decouple the above pattern from the phone number pattern, and say "apply this to pattern x, whatever pattern x may be, it cannot contain 10 or more character".

```
 /(.)\1{10,}/
```

Attempted solution:

1.) I nest the below pattern into parenthesis, so it is all in the 1st capturing group

```
^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

2.) insert below pattern into a negative lookahead, parenthesis removed from first pattern, as I want the first capturing group to be outside of the negative lookahead

```
.\1{10,}
```

What I end up with:

```
(?!.\1{10,})(^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)
```

expected result: 111-111-1111 fails
actual: 111-111-1111 passes

Answer (score 0):

Inside the negative lookahead, capture a digit, then repeatedly match `-*\1`. If that matches 9 (or more) times, then you have 10 repeated numbers:

```
^(?!(\d)(?:-*\1){9})((1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/BcfMvW/1

Comment: ok so I changed it so that if one number is different, ``` (?!(\d)(?:-*\1){9})(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}````,  so there _is_ a match, which is what I want. Let's say I was doing this in (nnn) nnn-nnnn format..how could I change this so that no only dashes are ignored but also spaces and paranthesis? It looks like you tried to accomplish this for dashes by putting a dash inside of a non-capturing group? Putting a space and a parathesis doesn't have the same effect as the dash.